# Position div relative height to parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the Log in text to be positioned at 33% height from the parent Card-Header-Background, but instead it looks like the height is being applied to the overall card.

```css
.Account-Details-Card-Background {
  width: 780px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 70px 0 rgba(90, 97, 105, 0.1), 0 10px 10px 0 rgba(90, 97, 105, 0.06), 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(90, 97, 105, 0.12), 0 2px 0 0 rgba(90, 97, 105, 0.11);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.Card-Header-Background {
  width: 780px;
  height: 69.6px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #e0e2e8, 0 -1px 0 0 #e0e2e8;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.Label---Log-in {
  width: 61px;
  height: 24px;
  font-family: SFProText;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3c5071;
}
```

```html
<div class="Account-Details-Card-Background" style="margin: 17.6vh 22.9vw; position: absolute">
  <div class="Card-Header-Background">
    <div>
      <div class="Label---Log-in text" style="margin: 33% 45%; position: absolute;">
        Log in
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

([*codepen*](https://codepen.io/jcald1/pen/exegWL))

Comment: Just an aside: `SFProText` does not reference the system font on macOS. If you want to use San Fransisco on macOS, use `system-ui`, or the older `-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont` ([*ref*](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/system-font-stack/#article-header-id-1)) in your font stack. If you have used the SFProText files from Apple to create a webfont, this is a violation of their terms of use: “*[...] you may use the Apple Font solely for creating mock-ups of user interfaces [...]*” (from the license included with the download).

Comment: @MTCoster,  Thanks.  I'm actually overriding it using:   font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif !important;.  It sounds like I should add system-ui before -apple-system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use inline style if you don't have to.

To achieve what you want you can just use `top: 33%` as I did here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYOdRB

Please let me know if that's what you need.

Comment: SeReGa, no the Log in should be in the Card-Header-Background at the top, just 33% down within that section.

Comment: Then you should not use `position: absolute`... take a look again in the link, you can use fixed `top` value. because your `height` is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems obvious now, but what I needed was padding not margin.